# how to do heavy operations on Application Server while using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, application-server

As a beginner question, I need to do some intensive image processing calculations for my app but it's obvious the app can't handle it by itself. Is there a suggested way to delegate heavy operations on the application server side in Android , considering I will need to use Firebase for the db - webservice operations by the way?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have certain computationally heavy operations that you don't want to run in the app, you could consider running them in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). There is even an [example of generating thumbnails of images](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#execute_intensive_tasks_in_the_cloud_instead_of_in_your_app) this way.

You could also run the operations on your own server, in which case you'll integrate with Firebase through its [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). This SDK gives your server full administrative access to the Firebase project, so it can do both regular operations and things that require elevated access permissions.

Comment: That was a very useful answer I have been looking for, thank you a lot.